# push object in array ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I need to push object in `ngFor` but I got error `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable<MyDataType[]>'`.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-with-observable-array-rvfand) demo code

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of myObservableArray | async'>
    {{item.value}}
</div>
```

**Component**

```
  getData() {
    if (!this.myObservableArray) {
      this.myObservableArray = this.myService.getData();
      this.myObservableArray.push({"id":3, "value":"value_4"});
    }
  }
```

**Service**

```
mydata: MyDataType[] = [
    {"id":1, "value":"value_1"},
    {"id":2, "value":"value_2"},
    {"id":3, "value":"value_3"}
  ];

  getData():Observable<MyDataType[]>
  {
    let data = new Observable<MyDataType[]>(observer => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              observer.next(this.mydata);
          }, 4000);
    });
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-with-observable-array-yddxbd?file=app/app.component.ts) I added one more method to service to add or update.

```
  addOrUpdate(item:MyDataType){
    var elem=this.mydata.find(element=> element.id==item.id);
    if(elem){
      elem.value=item.value;
    }
    else{
      this.mydata.push(item);
    } 
  }
```

and call it inside component

```
this.myService.addOrUpdate({"id":3, "value":"value_4"});
```

Comment: Actually, it not replace `value:'value_3'` with `value:'value_4'` base on `id`

Comment: Ohh you wanr add or update due to id of item. I saw push method. It always add new one . I will check it